PM2 Forces Node.js to Use Port 5000 Despite Explicit Configuration for Port 5001
I am trying to run a Node.js application with Express and MongoDB using PM2. The application is configured to run on port 5001, but even after explicitly setting the port to 5001, PM2 is still binding the application to port 5000. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
    const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// Initialize app
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON
app.use(express.json());

// Environment variables
dotenv.config();

// MongoDB Connection
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/devtrust', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
.catch((err) => console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err));

// User model
const User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
}));

// Signup route (create user)
app.post('/api/signup', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    // Input validation
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email and password are required' });
    }

    // Check if user already exists
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser) return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User already exists' });

    // Hash the password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    // Save the user
    const user = new User({ email, password: hashedPassword });
    await user.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created successfully' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error creating user', error: err.message });
  }
});

// Login route (authenticate user)
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Input validation
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email and password are required' });
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials' });

    // Compare passwords
    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isPasswordValid) return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials' });

    // Generate JWT token
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' });
    res.json({ token });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error logging in', error: err.message });
  }
});

// Test route to verify the server is running
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Server is working' });
});

// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

Steps Taken:
I explicitly set the PORT environment variable to 5001 in my .env file and inside the server.js file.
I started the server using PM2 with the following command:
bash
Copy code
PORT=5001 pm2 start server.js --name devtrust-backend -f
I confirmed that the server is still listening on port 5000 and not on 5001, even though the application is configured to use port 5001.
What I’ve Tried:
Stopping and deleting the PM2 process using pm2 stop all and pm2 delete all, then restarting it with PORT=5001 pm2 start server.js.
Checking if another process is using port 5000 and killing it (lsof -i :5000 and kill -9 ).
Checking the logs using pm2 logs devtrust-backend, but it still shows Server running on port 5000 instead of 5001.
Printing out the port to the console in the server.js file to verify which port is being used.
My Question:
Why does PM2 still bind the server to port 5000 even though I have set PORT=5001? How can I force PM2 to use the correct port?

This issue arises because PM2 doesn't pass the PORT environment variable properly when using inline declarations like:
 PORT=5001 pm2 start server.js


Ensure your .env file is correctly configured with: PORT=5001.

Stop and delete all existing PM2 processes to avoid conflicts:


    pm2 stop all
    pm2 delete all


Create an ecosystem.config.js file to manage environment variables explicitly.

Example:


module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'devtrust-backend',
      script: './server.js',
      env: {
        PORT: 5001,
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      },
      env_production: {
        PORT: 5001,
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],
};



